# Launch jar files on 64 bit java in Windows 7

Tags: java, 64-bit

I wanted to run java programs on a 64 bit Windows 7 computer and I have a 64 bit Java VM. How do I launch the jar files via command line ? It seems that 64 bit Windows 7 have a seperation between 32 bits and 64 bits programs.

Comment: sounds like a question for superuser, have you tried `java -jar file.jar` In case you have more than one JRE try giving the explicit path (C:\Programs\..., "C:\Programs (x86)\...")

Comment: Does `java -jar /path/to/jar/jarFile.jar` work?

Answer (score 3):

Try giving the explicit path for each JRE you have installed:

- `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar yourfile.jar`
- `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar yourfile.jar`
- `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar yourfile.jar`

Make sure you have a 64 bit JRE and a 32 bit JRE. Most java software provided still needs a 32 bit JRE (as it uses JNI or other non-portable stuff).

Comment: What do you mean by "is still 32 bit"?

Comment: Having installed just a 64bit JDK/JRE I realized, that many projects still provide binaries that require a 32 bit JRE (JDownloader, JXplorer) so I had to compile myself or simply install a 32bit JRE as well.

Comment: Not unless they link in native code, like SWT.  A pure java program can be run unmodified on any Java SE JVM.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: if you provide features, someone will use them. Same case here. I don't want to look at the sources of every minor tool just to make sure that it runs on any JRE. I also run (closed source) apps having a "java-frontend" with a C++ backend using JNI.

Comment: Thanks this worked out for me (Win7 64bit). What suprises me the most, that a command like `java -jar my_awesome_jar.jar` does work in the console (cmd) but not in the run field (Start > Run)

Comment: @Markus I guess the run dialog makes use of another `%PATH%` setting, maybe even a fixed one. I haven't found any info on that so it is still just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I commented, but since somebody else agrees I'll post it as an answer instead:

`java -jar /path/to/jar/jarFile.jar`

Take care to note what mbx said too:

> In case you have more than one JRE try giving the explicit path (C:\Programs..., "C:\Programs (x86)...")

Answer (score 0):

*Some* jar files have information in them allowing to be executed with the `-jar` switch.  If that information is not present you must use the `-cp myjar.jar my.main.method.class` argument to java.exe to execute  your program.

Basically, if you install Java (the easiest is through http://java.com) then you can use that to run Java programs.  It takes care of the correct version.

But it is not a problem to run a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit system - the primary limitation is that your application is limited to a few gigabytes of memory.

So, if you can run `java -version` you will be fine with just using the default java command available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Some Jar's I've had to lunch using the java.exe that is in the SysWOW64 folder.

```
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\java.exe -jar /path/to/jar/file.jar
```